# askYesNo no found function

Tags: r

I am trying to eliminate some columns through askYesNo but the function at the end does not execute me when the value is true, can you help me

```
emp.data <- data.frame(
  emp_id = c (1:5), 
  emp_name = c("Rick","Dan","Michelle","Ryan","Gary"),
  salary = c(623.3,515.2,611.0,729.0,843.25), 
  
  start_date = as.Date(c("2012-01-01", "2013-09-23", "2014-11-15", "2014-05-11",
                         "2015-03-27")),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)


date_Na = list("emp_name")

Delete<- function(){ 
  
  Answer = askYesNo("you want to remove the columns")
  
  if (Answer  == "TRUE" ) emp.data <- emp.data[ ,-which(names(emp.data) %in% date_Na)]
  else print("Columns are not deleted")
}
```

when executing the function it does not delete the emp_name column

Answer (score 2):

Up front: the issue is due to **Invisibility**.

A few things:

1. The return value from [`askYesNo`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/askYesNo.html) is a `logical`, so `== "TRUE"` is just overkill and doing silent coercion from a logical to `character`. You can just do `if (Answer) ...`.
2. Since the result *can* be `NA` (if "canceled"), then your conditional will fail if the user cancels. In that case, you really should be explicitly checking for `NA` values as well with `if (!is.na(Answer) && Answer) ...`.
3. Regardless, your function *is* returning value, it's just doing it invisibly. You can do one of three things:

   1. If you want to see it and not change the default "invisible" behavior, wrap it in `(..)`:

      ```r
      Delete()
      # you want to remove the columns (Yes/no/cancel) Yes

      (Delete())
      # you want to remove the columns (Yes/no/cancel) Yes
      #   emp_id salary start_date
      # 1      1 623.30 2012-01-01
      # 2      2 515.20 2013-09-23
      # 3      3 611.00 2014-11-15
      # 4      4 729.00 2014-05-11
      # 5      5 843.25 2015-03-27
      ```

      The `(..)` forces it to be visible.
   2. You can assign it to a variable and look at that variable itself,

      ```r
      ret <- Delete()
      # you want to remove the columns (Yes/no/cancel) yes
      ret
      #   emp_id salary start_date
      # 1      1 623.30 2012-01-01
      # 2      2 515.20 2013-09-23
      # 3      3 611.00 2014-11-15
      # 4      4 729.00 2014-05-11
      # 5      5 843.25 2015-03-27
      ```
   3. You can explicitly return thedata (see function definitions below) from the function, in which case it will "never" be invisible.

      ```r
      Delete()
      # you want to remove the columns (Yes/no/cancel) yes
      #   emp_id salary start_date
      # 1      1 623.30 2012-01-01
      # 2      2 515.20 2013-09-23
      # 3      3 611.00 2014-11-15
      # 4      4 729.00 2014-05-11
      # 5      5 843.25 2015-03-27
      ```
4. BTW, if the user selects "no", the data is not returned at all, even invisibly. Why is this? Because your function does not explicitly return the data. When there is no explicit `return(.)` statement, then a function returns the value of the last expression evaluated. In the case of a "no", this is `print`, which is just going to print and then return the (same) string:

   ```r
   (Delete())
   # you want to remove the columns (Yes/no/cancel) no
   # [1] "Columns are not deleted"   # this is printed from the function
   # [1] "Columns are not deleted"   # this is the return value from print, ergo the return value from the function
   ```

   (To see that `print` returns its string, use my `(..)` trick on `print`, which normally returns the string *invisibly*. `print("hello")` versus `(print("hello"))`.)
5. Defensively, however, if no columns are found from `date_NA`, then your function is going to return *nothing*, which is counter-intuitive, it should return *everything*. For demonstration,

   ```r
   date_Na <- "FOO" # obviously not going to be found here
   Delete()
   # you want to remove the columns (Yes/no/cancel) yes
   # data frame with 0 columns and 5 rows
   ```

   The fix is to not use `which`: negation of `%in%` will return a logical vector and always work here.

   ```r
   Delete <- function() { 
     Answer = askYesNo("you want to remove the columns")
     if (!is.na(Answer) && Answer) emp.data <- emp.data[ ,!names(emp.data) %in% date_Na]
     else print("Columns are not deleted")
     emp.data # return(emp.data) is what we "think" here, but 'return' is rarely necessary/beneficial
   }  
   Delete()
   # you want to remove the columns (Yes/no/cancel) yes
   #   emp_id emp_name salary start_date
   # 1      1     Rick 623.30 2012-01-01
   # 2      2      Dan 515.20 2013-09-23
   # 3      3 Michelle 611.00 2014-11-15
   # 4      4     Ryan 729.00 2014-05-11
   # 5      5     Gary 843.25 2015-03-27
   ```
6. Perhaps a tangent, but ... it's generally a bad idea to have a function rely on the presence of variables *outside* of its scope. You can always assign defaults to function arguments. I would recommend a function definition more along the lines of this, where the user can override the data:

   ```r
   Delete <- function(dat = emp.data, date_na = "emp_name") { 
     Answer = askYesNo("you want to remove the columns")
     if (is.na(Answer) && Answer) dat <- dat[ ,!names(dat) %in% date_na]
     else print("Columns are not deleted")
     dat # return(dat) is what we "think" here, but 'return' is rarely necessary/beneficial
   }
   ```

   This may be more OCD, but it starts down the road of some "good practices" in defensive programming.

Comment: I am seeing in example 5, when I run the example it does not save the Updated data frame, it only prints it to the console, but in the data frame it does not update from 4 variables to 3

Comment: Unless you save the results from `Delete()` into a variable (same or different), the function will never overwrite the `emp.data` that you see, that is the nature of functional programming. That behavior is called *side-effect*, where you run the function something else is changed elsewhere (not in the function's namespace). I strongly recommend that you not venture into side-effect while learning R programming, it can easily be problematic. Instead, explicitly save it with `emp.data <- Delete(emp.data)`.

Comment: Error in Delete(emp.data) : could not find function "Delete"  You can't find that function, what library are you using? I've been searching and I didn't find a function called Delete()

Comment: `could not find function "Delete"`?? Ummm, I'm confused. I've updated it several times here in my answer, and you have it defined in your question, so whatever you did broke your process. Try defining it again (from your question, or from my answer if you accept my recommendations).

Answer (score 0):

You're not saving the output as its own variable, so there's nothing to show that the function is indeed deleting the column. Try saving the output of `Delete()` as a variable or `print`ing the output, which should return what you're expecting.

```
new.emp.data <- Delete()
```

```
> new.emp.data

  emp_id salary start_date
1      1 623.30 2012-01-01
2      2 515.20 2013-09-23
3      3 611.00 2014-11-15
4      4 729.00 2014-05-11
5      5 843.25 2015-03-27
```

I'd also recommend passing the data frame as an argument to the function rather than relying on the external environment.

Comment: This is a very simple example of what I am doing, I just need to know why my code does not eliminate the column, in reality I am doing it on a large scale and in a more automatic way it is not a variable, it is more than 100 and the idea is that interact if you want to delete the columns or not